# In angular when I trying to put multiple value: Parser Error in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

```
Unexpected token <= at column 26 in [product.quantity > 50 or <=200] in /~/src/app/Components/products/products.component.html@30:18
```

Actually I am new to angular application...
above error has occur when I am trying multiple ngIf directive to using for get  if the quantity is less than or equal to 50, ‘Lower Inventory Level’. If the quantity is greater than 50 and less than or equal to 200, ‘Average Inventory Level’ and if it is greater than 200, ‘Sufficient Inventory Level’.

```
<div class="container-fluid main-content">
<div class="row">
    <section class= "col-md-12">
        <div class="mt-3 mb-3">
            <h3>Product List</h3>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-light t-head">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Product Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Product Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Created Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity in Kgs</th>
                    <th scope="col">Availability</th>
                    <th scope="col">Product Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
            <th scope="row">{{product.productId}}</th>
            <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{product.productDescription}}</td>
            <td>{{product.createdDate}}</td>
            <td>{{product.unitPrice}}</td>
            <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
            <td>
                <p *ngIf="product.quantity <= 50"> Lower Inventory </p>
               <p *ngIf="product.quantity > 200">Sufficent Inventory</p>
               <p *ngIf="product.quantity > 50 or <=200">Average Inventory Level</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-eye icon"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o icon"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `product.quantity > 50 || product.quantity <=200`

Answer (score 0):

After an or/and you have to specify which variable you want to check.
In your case you have to add the `product.quantity` again after the `or`

As [@Robby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) commented the code should look like:

`product.quantity > 50 || product.quantity <=200`